# How to completely remove toggle button bootstrap

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I want to remove toggle button in the navbar. My site is on ASP.NET and Bootstrap 3. I want to completely remove it, so when the browser window resizes, menu items should stay in their places.

Answer (score 0):

Just add these to your css:

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
  display: block!important;
}

.navbar-nav>li, .navbar-nav {
  float: left !important;
}

.navbar-nav.navbar-right:last-child {
  margin-right: -15px !important;
}

.navbar-right {
  float: right!important;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle with above codes: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/t4ym3/49/

Comment: thank you very much. I found another solution. I decided to not delete the toggle button. I solved that in another way. I wanted to delete because I had some problems with navbar height. But, again, thank you